# ScrollView in Android Nougat keeps scrolling to top when typing in EditText but works in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, scrollview, android-softkeyboard

Android **ScrollView** layouts can only contain one child element, so multiple child elements must be wrapped inside another layout element before being placed into a **ScrollView** element.

I have a main **FrameView** wrapping a **ScrollView** which wraps another **FrameView**, and inside that there are a number of **EditText** elements.

The layout looks something like this:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <FrameLayout>
            </EditText>
            </EditText>
        </FrameLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

It is all done programmatically, and works quite well. When the soft keyboard appears, the outer-most frame layout and scroll view are resized, and the contents scroll perfectly within the reduced area. It even scrolls to the selected edit text element when the soft keyboard pops up.

The problem is, even though the selected edit text is visible above the soft keyboard, **the scroll view automatically scrolls to the top every time a key is pressed.** I have to scroll down again to the focused edit text, but it scrolls to the top again with every keystroke of the soft keyboard.

I only have three test devices, one Nougat and two Lollipops, and **this issue occurs only on the Nougat**.

**What could be causing this strange behavious?**

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is by disabling scroll view before we update values in editText

```
 scrollview.setEnabled(false)
```

and then enabling scroll view after updating editText

```
scrollview.setEnabled(true)
```

Comment: The problem with that approach is that a multiline EditText with a height greater than the visible area above the soft keyboard will remain hidden. So the scroll view must be allowed to scroll for such adjustments. Is there a way to limit the scrolling, perhaps?

Comment: Also, its no longer possible to disable scroll views that way.